# How do I create a hierarchy tree using 2 one-dimensional arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to create a tree using two arrays - the first array contains integers that need to be converted into a hierarchy/tree/nested array, and the second array contains the numbers which trigger the branching.

I've been successful in slicing the first array into branches as a basic test, but I think I'm missing something in the recursive function `makeBranch` needed to nest the arrays correctly.

This works:

```
var sequence = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9, 7, 14, 13, 15, 23, 21, 22, 17, 20, 19, 17, 23, 24, 16, 11, 6, 10, 5],
breaks = [ 0, 17, 23 ];

var tree = [];
for (var i = 0, imax = sequence.length; i<imax; ++i) {
    var val = sequence[i];
    if (breaks.lastIndexOf(val) != -1) {
        tree.push([]);
    }
    tree[tree.length-1].push(val);
}
console.log(tree); // **** First test - passes
```

Using the same arrays, and it produces a very strange result:

```
var tree = makeBranch(sequence, 0, breaks);
console.log(tree);  // **** Second test - fails

function makeBranch(sequence, i, breaks) {

    var branch = [];
    for (var imax = sequence.length; i<imax; ++i) {
        var val = sequence[i];
        if (breaks.lastIndexOf(val) != -1) {
            branch.push( makeBranch(sequence.slice(i+1), i+1, breaks) );
        } 
        branch.push(val);
    }

    return branch;

}
```

Basically, I'd like to turn this array:

```
[0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9, 7, 14, 13, 15, 23, 21, 22, 17, 20, 19, 17, 23, 24, 16, 11, 6, 10, 5]
```

into this (or something similar):

```
[0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9, 7, 14, 13, 15, [23, 21, 22, [17, 20, 19], [17]], [23, 24, 16, 11, 6, 10, 5]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the algorithm supposed to know that one of those breaks should start a new branch on the parent instead of on the current branch it's building up? i.e. how should it know that the result shouldn't be: `[0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9, 7, 14, 13, 15, [23, 21, 22, [17, 20, 19, [17, [23, 24, 16, 11, 6, 10, 5]]]]]`?

Comment: Project specs changed overnight, so this problem just solved itself. I'll keep Simone's code handy just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tree = function (seq, breaks) { 
    var res = [], n;
    for(var i = 0; i < seq.length; ) {
        if(breaks.indexOf(seq[i]) != -1) {
            for(var j = i+1; j < seq.length; j++) {
                if(breaks.indexOf(seq[j]) != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            n = j;
            var branch = tree(seq.slice(i+1, n), breaks);
            branch.unshift(seq[i]);
            res.push(branch);
            i+=branch.length;
        } else {
            res.push(seq[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

tree([0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9, 7, 14, 13, 15, 23, 21, 22, 17, 20, 19, 17, 23, 24, 16, 11, 6, 10, 5], [0,17,23])

[[0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 9, 7, 14, 13, 15], [23, 21, 22], [17, 20, 19], [17], [23, 24, 16, 11, 6, 10, 5]]
```